# How to access methods of object passed via props to component

Tags: vue.js

I have a model class for an address where I've defined a method to return the full street (combined from two seperate properties on the address model). Now I wanted to pass such an object via props to a component and use the full street method to display it.

Unfortunately, it seems that the component loses the type of the object as the method call isn't recognized in the template...

Isn't it possible to use methods in templates?

Here's some simplified code:

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <AddressDisplay v-bind:address="AddressModel = { street: 'Bleeker', streetNr: '1' }" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import AddressDisplay from '@/components/AddressDisplay.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { AddressDisplay },
});
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ address.fullStreet }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  props: {
    address: { type: Object, required: true },
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.address.type);
  },
});
</script>
```

Type definition for model:

```
class AddressModel implements Model {
  street = '';
  streetNr = '';

  get fullStreet(): string {
    return this.street + ' ' + this.streetNr;
  }
}
```

What happens: nothing! There is no error message, but nothing is displayed. The console print type 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you write it like this: `v-bind:address="AddressModel = { street: 'Bleeker', streetNr: '1' }"`? What do you expect? Especially when you don't even import "AddressModel". Have a look at examples https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/class-component.html#data

This will probably work:

```
<template>
  <div>
     <AddressDisplay v-bind:address="address" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import AddressDisplay from '@/components/AddressDisplay.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  components: { AddressDisplay },
  data(){ return {
   address: { street: 'Bleeker', streetNr: '1' }
  }}
});
</script>
```

Comment: The code I've posted is just a simplified extract. The model class AddressModel is imported on a global level. How does your code know that it is an object of class AddressModel and that the method "fullStreet" can be used?

Comment: Stick to examples and try to do as it there, for example {{ address.fullStreet }} will not work because this is just function and not reactive getter on vue instance

Comment: So basically it's not possible to use class methods in components? That's what I suspected. So I have to pass the fullStreet to the component as value or do you see a better solution?

Comment: Probably yes, or create getter on the instance level that willd epend on values from object